# ngRepeat momentarily shows duplicated list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, get, typescript, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a modal that pops up on a button click. The content of the modal is a list of items. This list is stored in the controller, and is populated by some data from the response of a GET request.

Whenever I open the modal repeatedly, which implicitly calls the update to the list, momentarily I see multiple copies of the list - approximately one copy for each click. The displayed list then resolves itself to what is actually stored in the list.

Could this be an issue with the controller or html, or is it some sort of side-effect from ngRepeat?

The following are snippets from the html file:

```
<li ng-repeat="itemin vm.items">{{item.name}}</li>

<a href="#" onclick="togglePanel('Panel')" ng-click= "vm.getItems()">View Items</a>
```

And from the controller:

```
getItems(): angular.IPromise<core.IItem> {
        var self: Controller = this;
        return this.itemDataService.getItems()
        .then(function(response: any): angular.IPromise<core.IItem> {
          self.items = response.data;
          return response;
        },
        function(response: any): angular.IPromise<core.IItem> {
          self.items = [];
          return response;
        });
    }
```

Please ask if you need to see more code.

Edit: Extra code...
The onClick being called:

```
function toggleSavedSearchPanel(id)
{
    var e = document.getElementById(id);

    if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display=='')
    {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else
    {
        e.style.display = 'block';
        e.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue was with my CSS code; there was a transition: 0.2s in the css for the list. Removing it solved all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Some more code would be helpful. For example, you have an onclick attribute on the a tag, plus the ng-click event. Its hard to say whats going on without knowing what the onclick function is doing.

Also, in the view, you are attaching the items to a property on the scope named vm, but in your controller you are attaching it directly to this/self. Is there more code that moves it to the vm object?

It sounds like you are dealing with a timing issue around your API calls, but its hard to know for sure without seeing more code.

Comment: Concerning your second paragraph, I guess he is using the *controller as* syntax.

Comment: I would guess that's the case too, but we don't know for sure without seeing that code.

Comment: I have added the code for the onClick event. The ng-click calls the getItems() function which I originally posted. "vm" is the reference to the controller I am using - I hope you can trust me on that one. I think the problem could well be down to timing - if this is the case, how can I get around it?

Comment: I figured out the problem; there was a transition: 0.2s in the css for the list. Removing it solved all the problems. Thanks for your help.